# How do I view my HTML webpage on my phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have create a HTML webpage which also uses CSS and JS. When I view this on my PC it works and looks how it should.

What is the best way to put this on my phone?
I tried to put all the relevant files onto my phone but it will only load the base HTML, all the files were in the same folder as the HTML code only references the name of the CSS and JS as they are in the same file on the PC.

I am referencing the CCS as: `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` and the script as `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">`

I am opening the HTML on my PC with Google Chrome and trying to view it on my phone with google chrome as well.
I have an android phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referencing the files relatively (e.g. `/css/theme.css` instead of `C:\Users\JackU\project\css\theme.css`)?

Comment: Also, what are you opening the html file with?

Comment: @JakeSteam I am referencing the files as just `scr="script.js"` and `href="style.css"`. I am opening it on my PC with chrome and on my phone with chrome too. I will update my question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a local server to host the webpage, and navigate to the private IP of your pc from your mobile device if they are connected to the same network.

I prefer [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) npm package for this. Simply type `npm install -g live-server`. Navigate to the directory your website is located at then run `live-server`. It will also show the port you are running on.

To find out your private ip address, open another command line and type `ifconfig` (or `ipconfig`if you are on windows).

Navigate to ip-address:port-number in your mobile device and you will see your website. Example private ip address and port number: 192.168.1.40:8080

Comment: Brilliant thanks for you help. Struggled to start with as I didn't have `nodejs` installed but works now!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way for previewing on the mobile device is using websites such as :
https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?
I hope this helps you to determine your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to test your website on a phone you can connect you phone via USB and connect your chrome desktop with chrome mobile.

Here is the guide from Google:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

This should allow you to open and edit the site on your computer and view it on your phone to see if it works. You also get to use the desktop devtools while viewing the page on your phone.

For a permanent solution you can host your site on a webserver and connect to it over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

[image: More controls device toolbar]You can view the mobile version on your pc.
To do that,

1. open the website you want to view
2. press `ctrl + shift + I`(This opens the Inspector)
3. press `ctrl + shift + M`(Toggles the device toolbar)

You can even view the screen in different screen sizes

Answer (score 2):

Try following steps:

1. Make sure your pc and mobile are connected to the same network.
2. In Vscode install `live server` extension. After installation, it will appear on
   the status bar as `Go Live`.
3. Run the extension. You can then see the site running on a `port_number`(like: 3000).
4. Now type in cmd(windows): `ipconfig`.
5. From there copy the `Address IPv4`.
6. Then go to your mobile and type like this `Adress IPv4:port_number` you will see your
   site running on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Start the webpage with your IDE so it's exposed to a port on your computer.
Look up the IP of your computer and make sure you are on the same network with your mobile device. Navigate in your browser to your PC's ip + port and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your css styling inside the html markup and open it in your phone. It will work. Not sure if it will display your images though, but you can test the responsiveness of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Download open in browser app from play store. Then go to your internal storage on your mobile device and open with: open in browser.

Comment: This answer doesn't help a lot. The man already knows how to open the page. He has issues with loading its resources.

Comment: Please read the article of SO how to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: The resources from css and images will load when you the open in browser app